# Same LINQ query using joins but different conditions

Tags: c#, linq

I have some very similar LINQ queries:

```
var city = "Hamburg";

var query1 = 
    from c in DB.Customers
    join address in DB.Addresses on c.ID equals address.CustomerID
    where address.City == city
    select c;

var query2 = 
    from c in DB.Customers
    join address in DB.Addresses on c.ID equals address.CustomerID
    where address.City.StartsWith(city)
    select c;

etc.
```

I want to use a loop to create the queries to reduce redundancy:

```
var city = "Hamburg";

var expressions = new Expression<Func<string, bool>>[] {
    a => a == city,
    a => a.StartsWith(city)
};

for(int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
    queries.Add(
        from c in DB.Customers
        join address in DB.Addresses on c.ID equals address.CustomerID
        where expressions[i](address.City) 
        select c
        );
}
```

But I don't know how to create the expression array now. Any idea?

Comment: Honestly this looks like a job for a stored procedure.

Comment: What is your expected result?  One list, `i` lists?

Comment: @Hogan I expect `i` lists which contain customers that are filtered by the different expressions.

Comment: with Expression<Func<Customer, Addresse, bool>> ?

Comment: @asawyer only if you assume that, behind EF, there is a db that is compatible with stored procedure, what about SQLite ?

Comment: I have updated the question with more information.

Comment: As an aside: in EF, `join` is almost never required. Do you not have a navigation property like `Customer.Addresses`?

Comment: Thanks for your help. The answers of Lee, Tilak also seem to to what I want. But I had to choose one answer and I think the answer of lazyberezovsky matches my example case best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var city = "Hamburg";

// predicate should accept Address
var expressions = new Expression<Func<Address, bool>>[] {
    a => a.City == city,
    a => a.City.StartsWith(city)
};

foreach(var predicate in expressions) {
    queries.Add(
        DB.Customers.Join(
           DB.Addresses.Where(predicate), // filtering here
           c => c.ID, 
           a => a.CustomerID, 
           (c, a) => c) // return customer
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Join` method directly instead of using the query syntax:

```
public IQueryable<Customer> FindCustomers(Expression<Func<Customer, Address, bool>> predicate)
{
    return DB.Customers.Join(DB.Addresses, c => c.ID, a => d.CustomerID, (c, a) => new { Address = a, Customer = c})
        .Where(pair => predicate(pair.Address))
        .Select(pair => pair.Customer)
}
```

or you could pass both the `Customer` and `Address`:

```
public IQueryable<Customer> FindCustomers(Expression<Func<Customer, Address, bool>> predicate)
{
    return DB.Customers.Join(DB.Addresses, c => c.ID, a => d.CustomerID, (c, a) => new { Address = a, Customer = c})
        .Where(pair => predicate(pair.Customer, pair.Address))
        .Select(pair => pair.Customer)
}
```

then you can create your array as:

```
IQueryable<Customer>[] queries = expressions.Select(expr => FindCustomers(expr)).ToArray();
```

Comment: The problem is that the predicate needs to access a property of the address but when I join with `(c, a)=>c` I can only use the customer in my predicate or am I missing something?

Comment: @Dennis - I've changed it to use the `Address` instead of the `Customer`.

Answer (score 1):

You can save common join portion in common query.

```
var query = from c in DB.Customers
         join address from DB.Addresses on c.ID equals address.CustomerID
         select new {A=a, C=c};
var query1 = query.Where ( item => item.A.temp == item.C.test).Select (item => item.C);
var query2 = query.Where ( item => item.A.temp2 == item.C.test2).Select (item => item.C);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var queries=(
    from f in
        new Func<Address, bool>[] { 
            x => x.City==city, 
            x => x.City.StartsWith(city)
            }
    select
        from c in DB.Customers
        join address in DB.Addresses on c.ID equals address.CustomerID
        where f(address)
        select c
    ).ToArray();
```

1. You are creating an `expression array`, that means you are resulting an `expression array` after all; you don't need to make delegates an `expression array`.
2. You don't need `foreach`
3. If you will later add more expressions to `queries`, then change `ToArray()` to `ToList()`
4. If You want to make `Func<Address, bool>` be modified before you generate the `queries`, then define a local variable for it, and just replace the `Func<Address, bool>[]`

Comment: Thank you. What is `Association Bonus`, I just got that notice.